# .Net 8 Maui Nuget Packages missing and can't be installed

Tags: .net, maui, .net-8.0

I just upgraded my .Net Maui 7 project to .Net 8 and many things are broken, but for starters the nuget packages are all marked as missing and when I attempt to reinstall them nothing happens.

I do see this error:

```
Assets file 'C...\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-ios'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-ios' in the TargetFrameworks for your project
```

I have deleted the obj folder and run dotnet restore.

Attached is my csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-maccatalyst;net8.0-ios;net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
    <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>PopUpShop.Mobile.Maui</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>PopUp Shop</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>net.popupmobile.popupshop</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationIdGuid>975dcd8e-330e-48bc-bf84-911e730dcee2</ApplicationIdGuid>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.29</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>39</ApplicationVersion>

    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">31.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-android|AnyCPU'">
  <ApplicationTitle>PopUp Shop</ApplicationTitle>
  <ApplicationId>net.popupmobile.popupshop</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-android|AnyCPU'">
  <ApplicationTitle>PopUp Shop</ApplicationTitle>
  <ApplicationId>net.popupmobile.popupshop</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
  <ApplicationTitle>PopUp Shop</ApplicationTitle>
  <ApplicationId>net.popupmobile.popupshop</ApplicationId>
  <CodesignEntitlements>Platforms\iOS\Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
  <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.29</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
  <ApplicationVersion>39</ApplicationVersion>
  <ApplicationTitle>PopUp Shop</ApplicationTitle>
  <ApplicationId>net.popupmobile.popupshop</ApplicationId>    
  <CodesignEntitlements>Platforms\iOS\Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-maccatalyst|AnyCPU'">
  <ApplicationTitle>PopUp Shop</ApplicationTitle>
  <ApplicationId>net.popupmobile.popupshop</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-maccatalyst|AnyCPU'">
  <ApplicationTitle>PopUp Shop</ApplicationTitle>
  <ApplicationId>net.popupmobile.popupshop</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0|AnyCPU'">
  <ApplicationTitle>PopUp Shop</ApplicationTitle>
  <ApplicationId>net.popupmobile.popupshop</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0|AnyCPU'">
  <ApplicationTitle>PopUp Shop</ApplicationTitle>
  <ApplicationId>net.popupmobile.popupshop</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios'">
  <ProvisioningType>automatic</ProvisioningType>
  <CodesignKey>Apple Development: Created via API (96CKZSNPV8)</CodesignKey>
  <CodesignProvision>VS: net.popupmobile.popupshop Development</CodesignProvision>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>popupshop.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>key</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass></AndroidSigningKeyPass>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass></AndroidSigningStorePass>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="8,8" TintColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\popup_splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="256,256" TintColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="Resources\AppIcon\popup_splash.svg" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Images\location_dot.svg" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Images\map.svg" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Images\shop.svg" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps" Version="7.0.52" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Fingerprint" Version="3.0.0-beta.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.Maui" Version="5.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\PopUpShop.Shared\PopUpShop.Shared.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <MauiXaml Update="Views\ForgotPassword.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Views\MauiMap.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Views\Menu.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Views\MyShops.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Views\PinPopUp.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Views\QRPopUp.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Views\Registration.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Views\Search.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
  <MauiXaml Update="Views\ShopDetails.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </MauiXaml>
</ItemGroup>
```

The site is complaining that the post is mostly code and asking for more details so I am typing here but I don't know any other details to share.

Comment: Are you on mac or on windows? On windows you can't build ios/mac apps. You will need a connection to MAC OS to build iOS apps on windows.

Comment: have you tried microsoft's upgrade assistant tool [0]? It might help with this issue. I'd guess "<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-maccatalyst" could be the real culprit. Also make sure all your target framework conditions in the propertygroups are upgraded.

[0] https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant-now-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Maui8 and .net-8.0 are close to release but still under development.

I have been looking at the weekly releases and in the current release for example, the net8.0/ios-arm64 target is missing.

Everything else is there. I expect that this issue will be resolved in the release next week. We are very close to ruling off Maui8 and .net-8.0. After that, Microsoft and collaborators start work on .NET9 and Maui9 a similar cycle that will complete same time next year.